# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'formValues'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to update my reducer every time a useSelector change its value, but I need to use the spread operator to keep the rest of the content of my reducer. But my useEffect gives the following warning:

React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'formValues'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps.

Is there a way to avoid this warning and keep the rest of state of my reducer?

My code useEffect code:

```js
const handleDispatch = useCallback(
    values => {
      dispatch(hrRequestHiringFormChangeValues(values));
    },
    [dispatch]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cepAddressValues.error !== true) {
      handleDispatch({
        ...formValues,
        state: cepAddressValues.state,
        city: cepAddressValues.city,
        neighborhood: cepAddressValues.neighborhood,
        address: cepAddressValues.street,
      });
    } else {
      handleDispatch({
        ...formValues,
        state: '',
        city: '',
        neighborhood: '',
        address: '',
      });
    }
  }, [cepAddressValues, handleDispatch]);
```

Answer (score 0):

in dependency array of hooks like useEffect, useCallback, useMemo you have to place all variables that are declared outside of this hook and you used it inside of hook function. In this case you use formValues in handleDispatch inside useEffect but you don't place it in dependency array.

```
[cepAddressValues, handleDispatch, formValues]
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that, formValues changes every time(it´s a big form), so it might cause a performance issue.

Comment: @Mvrocha So use you can store this value in reference. useRef, and update it by useEffect and pass this reference. Your solution is not stable... i had many problems with not passing some state to dependency array.. is "treatment of pimples with powder"

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Just one question, the useRef, won´t keep being updated? Since the formValue will change on every typed chacacter?

Answer (score 0):

Disable `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` inline

`(make sure that dependency is not required)`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (cepAddressValues.error !== true) {
      handleDispatch({
        ...formValues,
        state: cepAddressValues.state,
        city: cepAddressValues.city,
        neighborhood: cepAddressValues.neighborhood,
        address: cepAddressValues.street,
      });
    } else {
      handleDispatch({
        ...formValues,
        state: '',
        city: '',
        neighborhood: '',
        address: '',
      });
    }
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [cepAddressValues, handleDispatch]);
```

Check, is exist `react-hooks` plugin in eslint plugins
Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much!